# Batch Change wallpaper from internet

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do a batch file that change my wallpaper by dowloading the last `APOD` pic and setting it as wallpaper. I have it done however there is a part I do not understand.

This is the batch script:

```bat
bitsadmin.exe /transfer GETWALLPAPER %LastImg% %SaveDest%
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %savedest% /f
timeout /t 01
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

for /l %%x in (1,1,10) do  (
   reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d %savedest% /f
   RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
   timeout /t 01
)
```

Without the `for` loop. Sometimes the wallpaper update, sometimes not. I don't understand it.

Is there a way to make this script reliable without the ending loop ?

*I run Windows 10 - 64 Bits*

Edit 23/01/19 : Question is still open if anyone has an answer. The script works but i need to loop 50 times this reg command to have it update in a reliable way.